# Keras model trained with Multi GPUs not loading on non gpu machine

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When Loading the generated h5 file I get the following error:

> ValueError: No model found in config file.

I have read about it and found out that i need to reload the model and save it for 0 gpu machine as written at:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11253#issuecomment-482467792

When doing as said there and added the following section:

```
x , y = build_resnet(x_train.shape[1:], 64, nb_classes)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
p_model = multi_gpu_model(model)
old_model = p_model.layers[-2]
old_model.save(save_path)
```

I have got the following error:

> ValueError: For multi-gpu usage to be effective, call `multi_gpu_model` with `gpus >= 2`. Received: `gpus=0`

When i try the following code:

```
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.load_weights('resNet_trained_on_multi.h5')
```

I have got the following error:

> ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 0 layers into a model with 26 layers.

What can i do to recover the multi gpu weights/model that i have saved?
I have the following files(all generated at the same time):

- resNet_trained_on_multi.h5 - size 6KB
- resNet_trained_on_multi.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 - size 12MB
- resNet_trained_on_multi.ckpt.index - size 23KB
- resNet_trained_on_multi.ckpt.meta - size 4MB

generated using the following save code:

```
def saveModel(model):
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    h5_file = 'resNet_trained_on_multi.h5'
    ckpt_file = 'resNet_trained_on_multi.ckpt'

    saver.save(kerasBackend.get_session(), ckpt_file)
    print("[OUTPUT] Checkpoint saved to: " + ckpt_file)

    model.save(h5_file)
    print("[OUTPUT] H5 Model saved to: " + h5_file)
```

Comment: For the first ValueError the problem ist that you have to add `multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)` to the function call as the default value is `gpus=None`.

Comment: Yes but i am trying to run it on my local none gpu machine, is it even possible?

Comment: Yes I did it like you explained it in the first try and for me it worked (including the `gpus=2`). This compiles it as a gpu model with a lot of stuff around it. So with `old_model = p_model.layers[-2]` you just grab the model itself and you can save it without the gpu overhead.